# Node.js grab all files from zip file and rezip

Tags: javascript, node.js, zip

I want to write a node.js service downloading and regenerating zip files. The zip file downloaded may

**Case 1.** includes a couple files.

**Case 2.** the files be contained in a folder and the folder is zipped.

What I want to do is remove the folder and put the files directly in the zip file. In other words, all case 2 should be transferred to case 1.

I don't want to unzip them, copy the files out and then zip them because it is a lot of process. Do you have any better idea to complete the task efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is impossible to do without unzipping. Problem is that inside zip file there is metadata of where and what, but then content of each file joined into single byte sequence and then processed. So file content depends on content of other files. So it is impossible to take out some piece of archive. Because both pieces will become broken then.